How can I suppress the error summary at the bottom of `stack test`
I like to have stack test --file-watch running in a terminal below my editor so when I make a change and save, it reruns my tests and gives feedback. However, in the output below, everything after the "aoc2024> Test suite aoc2024-test failed" is repeating the message above it. I always have to scroll up to see if it was a compiler error or a test failure.
Is there a way to suppress the summary at the bottom?
Failures:

  test/Day8Spec.hs:11:19: 
  1) Day8.Day8 should do sample 1
       expected: 14
        but got: 0

  To rerun use: --match "/Day8/Day8/should do sample 1/" --seed 1033064501

Randomized with seed 1033064501

Finished in 0.0115 seconds
16 examples, 1 failure, 1 pending



aoc2024> Test suite aoc2024-test failed
Completed 2 action(s).

Error: [S-7282]
       Stack failed to execute the build plan.
       
       While executing the build plan, Stack encountered the
       error:
       
       Error: [S-1995]
       Test suite failure for package aoc2024-0.1.0.0
           aoc2024-test:  exited with: ExitFailure 1
       Logs printed to console
    


You could run an additional instance of ghcid so when that passes and this stack test doesn't you will know it's a test error and not compile error.
